# How to get JSON data output by event via runEvent() in ColdBox?

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfml, coldbox

I have an event that is outputting data via `event.renderData(data=mydata, "json")`.

When I access it via the browser, the JSON data is returned as expected. Though if I call the event from within another event, I only get an empty string returned.
I save the output like this:

```
savecontent variable="local.eventResult" {
  runEvent(event="mymodule:myhandler.myaction");
}
```

If I dump the data within the event, it looks ok. I have tried to get the data via `return event.renderData(data=mydata, "json");` and returning the data directly, i.e. `return mydata;`, without success.

What should I do to get the data as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question on the ColdBox Slack channel and received a response that this behavior is intentional.  You can not use `renderData()` to return output from `runEvent()`.  Here is the response I received from Luis M:

> RenderData is mostly used for the request to marshall data, not the event
>   if you want the event to return something, then just use `return`

Example:

```
function test( event, rc, prc  ) {
  return "<p>MyViewlet</p>";
}
```

In your example, if you want to output data as JSON, you could use the following in your handler:

```
function myAction( event, rc, prc  ) {    

    var myData = {
        fruit = "apple",
        vegetable = "carrot"
    };

    return serializeJSON( myData );

}
```